# Laravel white Screen of Death on Errors with proper permissions

Tags: php, debugging, nginx, laravel, virtual-machine

I'm setting my first project using Laravel, but it has been a big deal to show application errors.

It just works fine when everything is correct, but if there is any kind of errors, I get the white screen.

The app/storage folder is set to 777 (I know it shouldn't) and debug is true.

Nginx error log complains about a missing view/layout.html.php, which I think that has to do with the error view generation.

I'm working at homestead VM provoded in Laravel's website. I've created the project with composer and with laravel.phar boot from the VM and from host machine and I get the same situation.

This is artisan tail log:

```
#3 /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public/fazendafarao/bootstrap/compiled.php(8943): Illuminate\Exception\WhoopsDisplayer->display(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException))
#4 /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public/fazendafarao/bootstrap/compiled.php(8895): Illuminate\Exception\Handler->displayException(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException))
#5 /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public/fazendafarao/bootstrap/compiled.php(692): Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleException(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException))
#6 /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public/fazendafarao/bootstrap/compiled.php(7425): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#7 /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public/fazendafarao/bootstrap/compiled.php(8031): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#8 /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public/fazendafarao/bootstrap/compiled.php(7978): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#9 /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public/fazendafarao/bootstrap/compiled.php(10747): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#10 /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public/fazendafarao/bootstrap/compiled.php(648): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public/fazendafarao/public/index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#12 {main} [] []
[2014-06-10 13:54:17] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Could not find resource 'views/layout.html.php' in any resource paths.(searched: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public/fazendafarao/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Exception/resources, /var/www/working/laravel-master/vendor/filp/whoops/src/Whoops/Handler/../Resources)' in /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public/fazendafarao/bootstrap/compiled.php:10631
Stack trace:
#0 /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public/fazendafarao/bootstrap/compiled.php(10513): Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler->getResource('views/layout.ht...')
#1 /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public/fazendafarao/bootstrap/compiled.php(10361): Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler->handle(Object(RuntimeException))
#2 /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public/fazendafarao/bootstrap/compiled.php(8837): Whoops\Run->handleException(Object(RuntimeException))
#3 /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public/fazendafarao/bootstrap/compiled.php(8943): Illuminate\Exception\WhoopsDisplayer->display(Object(RuntimeException))
#4 /home/vagrant/Code/L' in /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public/fazendafarao/bootstrap/compiled.php:10631
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleShutdown()
#1 {main} [] []
```

Does someone have a clue?

Comment: try to do an artisan tail and see what the log files say.

Comment: everytime i have the white screen "chmod -R 777 app/storage does it ;)

Comment: I've aready set 777 to app/storage.

Tail has returned: https://gist.github.com/romulocollopy/c7beb1f1032a26930bea

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it. Installing with "laravel new" as in http://laravel.com/docs/quick#installation caused some issues on dependencies. But it worked installing with composer.

Answer (score 0):

I found that running `php artisan optimize` fixed my issue (Laravel 4.2)